# How to set the "downloading window" back to the old way in IE 9?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

When I try to download/save a file in IE 9 the "Save", "Save as" options opens up at the bottom of the webpage which I then have to use a mouse to click on; how do I reset it back to how it was in IE 8 where I could choose "Open", "Save As" etc. with the keyboard?

Win 7 Pro.
IE 9.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyboard but is much harder, use the Tab key to highlight the save button, then use the up arrow to open it to select what you want to do, they definitely screwed up the ease of use.